# Async process to avoid to block user

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot application in the controller, I need to do some process (search user, send email) who can take some time. So I would like to avoid to block it (ui).

Because I return fragment page, I can't use directly @Async annotation

```
@PostMapping("/resetpassword")
public String getResetPasswordSend(@RequestParam String email){
    
    //process here

    return "fragments/forgetpasswordsend";
}
```

Comment: Are you *asking* if you can use the `@Async` annotation or *stating* that you can use the `@Async` annotation? If it's the latter, it is not clear what your question is. If the former, you may want to rephrase that a bit.

Comment: I updated to clarify

Comment: maybe a new private method, like `@Async sendEmailIfAddressExists(String email) {...` so the getResetPasswordSend call it in the "//process here" and returns immediately.